# Python Dropping columns containing large percentage of missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete columns containing a certain percentage of missing values. 
Below is a working example:

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', np.nan, 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
    'last_name': ['Miller', np.nan, 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
    'age': [42, '' , '', '', 73], 
    'sex': ['m', np.nan, 'f', 'm', 'f'], 
    'preTestScore': [4, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, np.nan, np.nan, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 
    'sex', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
df
 first_name last_name   age sex preTestScore    postTestScore
 0  Jason   Miller       42  m    4.0             25.0
 1  NaN     NaN              NaN  NaN             NaN
 2  Tina    Ali              f    NaN             NaN
 3  Jake    Milner           m    2.0             62.0
 4  Amy     Cooze       73   f    3.0             70.0

df = df.dropna(thresh=0.7*len(df), axis=1)
df
first_name  last_name   age sex
0   Jason   Miller      42  m
1   NaN     NaN             NaN
2   Tina    Ali             f
3   Jake    Milner          m
4   Amy     Cooze       73  f
```

How may I drop the 'age' column as well? I have spent hours using drop.na,  trying to put in zeros in the empty cells. I just can't figure out as to how to detect the missing cells in the 'age' column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `replace`, then `dropna`

```
df=df.replace({'':np.nan})
df = df.dropna(thresh=0.7*len(df), axis=1)
df
Out[858]: 
  first_name last_name  sex
0      Jason    Miller    m
1        NaN       NaN  NaN
2       Tina       Ali    f
3       Jake    Milner    m
4        Amy     Cooze    f
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! Works like a charm.. I will accept the answer as soon as I am able to (its not letting me accept right now).

Comment: @continuous_learner Yw btw next time you can add tag pandas;-)

Answer (score 2):

First replace `' '` or (Blanks) with `NaN` then use `dropna()`

```
df = df.replace({'':np.nan})
df

      first_name last_name   age  sex  preTestScore  postTestScore
0      Jason    Miller  42.0    m           4.0           25.0
1        NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN           NaN            NaN
2       Tina       Ali   NaN    f           NaN            NaN
3       Jake    Milner   NaN    m           2.0           62.0
4        Amy     Cooze  73.0    f           3.0           70.0
```

You can use following function to check missing value %

```
def missing(dff):
    print("Missing values in %")
    print(round((dff.isnull().sum() * 100/ len(dff)),2).sort_values(ascending=False))
    
missing(df)

Missing values in %
age              60.0
postTestScore    40.0
preTestScore     40.0
sex              20.0
last_name        20.0
first_name       20.0
dtype: float64
```

Let's say, you want to drop all the columns having 60% or more missing values

```
df = df.drop(df.loc[:,list((100*(df.isnull().sum()/len(df))>=60))].columns, 1)

  first_name last_name  sex  preTestScore  postTestScore
0      Jason    Miller    m           4.0           25.0
1        NaN       NaN  NaN           NaN            NaN
2       Tina       Ali    f           NaN            NaN
3       Jake    Milner    m           2.0           62.0
4        Amy     Cooze    f           3.0           70.0
```

Note: Age column (60 % missing values) is dropped.

Comment: May I know why do we need `df.index` in this piece of code `list((100*(df.isnull().sum()/len(df.index))>=60))]`. Just `len(df)` would work. Am I right?

Comment: @TheGreat: Yeah, len(df) will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

how about this using dropna from pandas:

```
def drop_columns(data, threshold):
    return(data.dropna(axis = 1, thresh = (len(data) * (1-threshold))))
```

(this is my first time answering so sorry if I'm not nailing the etiquette)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to drop columns having certain percentage of missing values :

```
df = df.drop(columns= [x for x in df if round((df[x].isna().sum()/len(df)*100),2) > 30 ])
```